# If we would give width and height to <table> then will it load quickly?

Tags: performance, xhtml

If We are using `table` for to show tabular data and if we would give width and height to `<table>` then will it load quickly? will page loading speed improved of `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a width and height won't make the total page load faster, since that depends on your network speed and the size of your page (in bytes).  But it may let the browser start drawing the table before the entire page is loaded, so the page may seem to load faster.

Comment: "When the page loads and the image size is already defined (ie. you've used the height and width tags), the browser knows where everything will be before the images are loaded. Otherwise the page has to wait and load the images before the text. Same goes for tables, so try to use width tags when possible on those as well for a speedier page." http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/load-time.shtml

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - The webweaver tip is poorly worded. Ned is correct.